# Unable to load cxf feature in Karaf 4.0

Tags: karaf

I am trying to use Karaf to host a REST service.  I am using version 4.0.0 M2 (as I'm early on in my prototype).  From what I have pieced together, in order to host a REST service, I can use Karaf Features to install the http and cxf features.

What I have done so far...

- started Karaf - started fine
- set it up to find my local maven repo - fine
- used `feature:repo-add mvn:org.apache.cxf.karaf/apache-cxf/3.0.4/xml/features` - that worked without error, and I can see the xml in my mvn repo
- ran `feature:install http` - that worked, and I can see evidence of the Jetty code running
- ran `feature:install cxf` - this fails

I am getting this message in the console

> karaf@root()> feature:install cxf Error executing command: Unable to
>   resolve root: missing requirement [root] osgi.identity;
>   osgi.identity=cxf-http-jetty; type=karaf.feature; version=3.0.4
>   [caused by: Unable to resolve cxf-http-jetty/3.0.4: missing
>   requirement [cxf-http-jetty/3.0.4] osgi.identity;
>   osgi.identity=org.apache.cxf.cxf-rt-transports-http-jetty;
>   type=osgi.bundle; version="[3.0.4,3.0.4]"; resolution:=mandatory
>   [caused by: Unable to resolve
>   org.apache.cxf.cxf-rt-transports-http-jetty/3.0.4: missing requirement
>   [org.apache.cxf.cxf-rt-transports-http-jetty/3.0.4]
>   osgi.wiring.package;
>   filter:="(&(osgi.wiring.package=org.eclipse.jetty.continuation)(version>=7.6.0)(!(version>=8.2.0)))"]]

If I look at the bundles that are there, I can see org.eclipse.jetty.continuation package in my system when http is installed

> 2015-05-08 09:29:02,928 | INFO  | pool-40-thread-1 |
>   FeaturesServiceImpl              | 6 - org.apache.karaf.features.core
>   - 4.0.0.M2 |   org.eclipse.jetty.continuation / 9.2.7.v20150116

So, it's at version 9.2.7.  If I understand the error back at installing cxf, it wants a version that is >= 7.6.0 and not >= 8.2.0.

Is there a version of the HTTP service that I can use with CXF?  I'm fairly new to Karaf, so I'm not sure how to specify an older version.  Thanks for any help.

Comment: So, instead of using Karaf 4.0, I installed Karaf 3.0.3 and, following the same steps, was able to install the cxf feature.  So, perhaps the real question is whether there is a roadmap for cxf to support karaf 4.0?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that's a known issue. Not sure though, if known to Karaf and CXF folks. I too had issue with Karaf 4.0.0, I couldnt even install http cxf. I then went back to Karaf 3.0.3 and things worked for me. I too have this concern! Does Apache Karaf project/team really consider its own Apache CXF ? Well, I doubt!

Comment: FYI - I've downloaded karaf 4.0.0.M3, and I've installed apache cxf 3.1.0 into it, and it works fine.  So, changes in my setup... karaf 4.0.0 M3 (instead of M2) and cxf 3.1.0 (instead of 3.0.4).  But, I can host my rest services just fine.

Answer (score 0):

Karaf 4.x comes with Jetty 9 (not 8). So, you have to update your CXF
version (3.11 for instance) or downgrade to Karaf 3 (which provides
Jetty 8).